# How can I retrieve elements from an HTML file that I attached to a GWT frame using setUrl()?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame` & displayed in an HTML file using `frame.setUrl(FILEPATH).`

I tried this code but it don't work:

```
frame.getElement().getElementsByTagName("table").getLength()
```

I want to fetch the width of a particular element in the HTML file and set the frame's width same to it.

I am using Eclipse with GWT Plugin.

EDIT: I got did it using these:

```
IFrameElement iframe = IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement());
Document frameDocument = iframe.getContentDocument();
String width= frameDocument.getElementsByTagName("table").getItem(0).getOffsetWidth() + "px";
frame.setWidth(tmpWidth);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @apanizo said, you'll want to use a `LoadHandler` to make sure the document is loaded in the frame.

Then, to read into the frame's document, you'll have to use `IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement())` or `frame.getElement().<IFrameElement>cast()` and then use [`getContentDocument()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/IFrameElement.html#getContentDocument%28%29).

```
IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement()).getContentDocument().getElementsByTagName("table").getLength()
```

A final note: this won't work if the document loaded in the frame is not from the same origin as your GWT app.

Answer (score 1):

Look waht [NodeList#getLength()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NodeList.html#getLength%28%29) states:

> The number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices is 0 to length-1 inclusive.

you can try with [Element#getOffsetWidth()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getOffsetWidth%28%29) or [Element#getStyle()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getStyle%28%29) then [Style#getWidth()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html#getWidth%28%29).

Sample code:

```
NodeList<Element> nodeList = frame.getElement().getElementsByTagName("table");

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = nodeList.getItem(i);
    System.out.println(element);
    System.out.println(element.getOffsetWidth());
    System.out.println(element.getStyle().getWidth());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. maybe is interesting for you to include a `LoadHandler` in order to wait until the iframe's content has been loaded (**otherwise the DOM search could be empty**) . Then, you can search inside the frame for the table element using GQuery selectors (like jQUery) and finally you set width.

Here is the code:

```
    final Frame yourFrame = new Frame("http://www.example.your.url.com");
    yourFrame.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        int elemWidth = GQuery.$(yourFrame).contents().find("table").width();
        yourFrame.setWidth(elemWidth+"px");

      }
    });
```

UPDATE: With @Manolo's comment!

Comment: The correct syntax for gQuery is: `$(yourFrame).contents().find("table").width()`

Comment: And if you want to use gQuery events: `$(yourFrame).on("load", new Function(){...});`